# Magento register double opt in doesn´t work

Tags: email, custom-options, register

I have set "Require Emails Confirmation" in Customer Configuration to Yes, but it dosen´t work if I register me I´m in my account andI would´t get a Confirmation Link Email !
What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you log in with the created and unconfirmed account? This might be an issue with your transactional emails if you are using a Magento version > 1.9

Comment: I´m using 1.8.1 and yes I can log in with the account and in manage customers  " Confirmed email": is  on yes by the account.